# How to vectorize/pipe through methods?

Tags: r, loops, methods, twitter, vectorization

I'm using [twitteR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/README.html) to get the followers for a few handles. When fetching a single user, this code works:

```
test <- getUser("BarackObama")

test_friends <- test$getFriends(10) %>% 
  twListToDF() %>%   
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(id = rowname) %>% 
  select(name, everything())
```

However, I'm not sure what's the cleanest way to iterate over a list of handles. The main obstacle I see at the moment is that I don't know how to pipe/vectorize over the `getFriends()` method (contra a `getFriends()` function). Plus, the object returned by `getFriends()` is not a DF, but has to be flattened (?) by `twListToDF()`, to then use `rbind()`.

For looping, this is as far as I got:

```
handles <- c("BarackObama", "ThePresObama")
  while (i < length(handles))  {
  user <- getUser(handles[i]) 
  friends <- user$getFriends() %>% 
  twListToDF() 
       }
```

With a bit more tinkering, I think I could get this to work, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

Comment: Look into functional programming with `purrr` functions

Comment: Hey, thanks for the note, @CalumYou. I started playing with `map()`, but I couldn't figure it out, given the object returned by `getUser()` and the method issue mentioned above. I'll keep at it.

Comment: I usually recommend people use [rtweet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/index.html) instead of `twitteR`. `rtweet` is more up to date, returns more usable data structures and handles authentication much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, using `rtweet`, it seems like there is a more elegant solution that might accomplish your goal. It extracts the followers of specified users into a dataframe, looks up followers by user, then binds that result to the original dataframe using `left_join` so that you can distinguish which users correspond to which followers.

```
library(rtweet)
handles <- c("BarackObama", "ThePresObama")
handles.friends <- get_friends(handles)
handles.data <- lookup_users(handles.friends$user_id) %>% 
    left_join(handles.friends)
```

The `pmap_*` functions from `purrr` might also help implement a solution using the `twitteR` library, and have generally helped me to implement non-vectorized functions, but unfortunately I'm unable to get `twitteR` authentication working.

Comment: Hi Ian—thanks for the answer! The first proposal didn't work (`pmap_dfr`...), the `rtweet` version did. In the second case, is there any chance you know how to store which friends are from which handle? Right now, the output is stored in one DF, without distinction of where each friend comes from.

Comment: Nvm, just need a left_join ;). Note that a complete answer requires a second command: `lookup_users(handles.friends$user_id)` and then `left_join.`

Comment: Great, glad to help out and that you've got it working. I had a suspicion `pmap_df` wouldn't work as I reported it since I wasn't able to try out a reprex using `twitteR`. I've edited my answer to reflect the working `rtweet` solution.